# How to create URL by using value of a column as param in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have a favorites table, with each visitor_id is a random string

```
         Favorites
-------------------------
| visitor_id | place_id |
-------------------------
| aab1       |     1    |
-------------------------
| aab2       |     2    |
-------------------------
| aab3       |     3    |
-------------------------
| ....       |   ...    |
-------------------------
```

Now, I want to create a url to link to each visitor_id. The url I want to create is something looks like this:

```
favorites/visitor/:visitor_id
```

Ex:

```
favorites/visitor/aab1
favorites/visitor/aab2
favorites/visitor/aab3
```

What is the correct syntax should I write in the route.rb and favorites_controller.rb or favorite.rb model to make this happens? And how to make the view will display the visitor_id according to the URL?

Ex:

```
favorites/visitor/aab1  ==> Display aab1 in view
favorites/visitor/aab2  ==> Display aab2 in view
favorites/visitor/aab3  ==> Display aab3 in view
```

PS: I don't have visitor controller, model or table. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code should work

```
#routes.rb
get "/favorites/visitor/:visitor_id", to: 'favorites#visitor', as: 'favorites_visitor'
```

The above route takes you to the url like <s>`favorites/visitor/1`</s> `favorites/visitor/aab1`, <s>but as you want it as `favorites/visitor/aab1` you should use [***friendly_id***](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem to generate those urls</s>.

Also the above route expects a method named `visitor` defined in `favorites_controller.rb`

***Note:***

I totally forgot that the value of `visitor_id` is a ***random string***, so you won't need `friendly_id` gem. I strike those lines to reflect it.

***Update:***

> How can I create a link to link to a specific visitor_id

You can use the below link,

```
<%= link_to "Visitor", favorites_visitor_path(@visitor) %>
```

Assuming you defined `@visitor` in the particular method of your `favorites_controller.rb`

Comment: Thank you. Now it works. But how can I create a link to link to a specific visitor_id. Ex: A link to link to "favorites/visitor/aab1"?

Comment: @PeterNguyen Great! Please accept my answer by ticking it green :)